# How reproducible / deterministic is Parquet format?

Tags: parquet, apache-arrow

I'm seeking advice from people deeply familiar with the binary layout of Apache Parquet:

Having a data transformation `F(a) = b` where `F` is fully deterministic, and same exact versions of the entire software stack (framework, arrow & parquet libraries) are used - how likely am I to get an **identical binary representation** of dataframe `b` on different hosts every time `b` is saved into Parquet?

In other words **how reproducible** Parquet is on binary level? When data is **logically the same** what can cause binary differences?

- Can there be some uninit memory in between values due to alignment?
- Assuming all serialization settings (compression, chunking, use of dictionaries etc.) are the same, can result still drift?

### Context

I'm working on a system for fully reproducible and deterministic data processing and computing dataset hashes to assert these guarantees.

My **key goal** has been to ensure that dataset `b` contains an **idendital set of records** as dataset `b'` - this is of course very different from hashing a binary representation of Arrow/Parquet. Not wanting to deal with the reproducibility of storage formats I've been computing **logical data hashes** in memory. This is slow but flexible, e.g. my hash stays the same even if records are re-ordered (which I consider an equivalent dataset).

But when thinking about integrating with `IPFS` and other **content-addressable** storages that rely on **hashes of files** - it would simplify the design a lot to have just one hash (physical) instead of two (logical + physical), but this means I have to guarantee that Parquet files are reproducible.

---

### Update

I decided to continue using logical hashing for now.

I've created a new Rust crate [arrow-digest](https://github.com/sergiimk/arrow-digest) that implements the stable hashing for Arrow arrays and record batches and tries hard to hide the encoding-related differences. The crate's README describes the hashing algorithm if someone finds it useful and wants to implement it in another language.

I'll continue to expand the set of supported types as I'm integrating it into the decentralized data processing [tool](https://github.com/kamu-data/kamu-cli) I'm working on.

In the long term, I'm not sure logical hashing is the best way forward - a subset of Parquet that makes some efficiency sacrifices just to make file layout deterministic might be a better choice for content-addressability.

Comment: I'm not quite knowledgeable enough on Parquet to answer this.  My gut says it is not deterministic and you may onto something with uninitialized padding.  However, I wanted to point out that there are many different ways to store the same data into a parquet file.  Writers can choose to write statistics or not write statistics, to use different size row groups or data page sizes, to use different encoding schemes and different compression schemes.  All of these result in different parquet files for the same data.

Comment: Thanks! Padding is what concerns me the most. The statistics and other settings are under my control, so if needs be I'd be willing to disable all of the extras as long as I can stays with Parquet format (due to its wide support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in arrow's implementation I would expect, but haven't verified the exact same input (including identical metadata) in the same order to yield deterministic outputs (we try not to leave uninitialized values for security reasons) with the same configuration (assuming the compression algorithm chosen also makes the deterministic guarantee).  It is possible there is some hash-map iteration for metadata or elsewhere that might also break this assumption.

As @Pace pointed out I would not rely on this and recommend against relying on it).  There is nothing in the spec that guarantees this and since the writer version is persisted when writing a file you are guaranteed a breakage if you ever decided to upgrade.   Things will also break if additional metadata is added or removed ( I believe in the past there have been some big fixes for round tripping data sets that would have caused non-determinism).

So in summary this might or might not work today but even if it does I would expect this would be very brittle.